# How to change Bootstrap Datepicker Language

Tags: datepicker, twitter-bootstrap-3

i have a Bootstrap Datepicker in my site, in default it use English Language, but my site use Indonesian Language. I wanna change bootstrap datepicker language to Indonesian for suitability.

Where is the codes in the library should I change? or is there any other plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official Bootstrap Datepicker, so its hard to give an answer, as you could be using any number of different date pickers.....

But I do know that [This One](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=component&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&todayBtn=false&language=it&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox) has pretty good language support, I believe the Indonesian language code is "id", in which case it supports this language.

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
   language: "id"
});
```