# Change language of Bootstrap Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using a date input with bootstrap-datepicker to show a calendar for the user to pick a date. I'm trying to change the calendar language to pt-BR and it is not working. I also can't change it to any other language.

I've tried this: [How to change Bootstrap Datepicker Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21357944/how-to-change-bootstrap-datepicker-language)
and this: [bootstrap-datepicker set language globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26487765/bootstrap-datepicker-set-language-globally)

I've tried to set the language to 'pt', 'pt-BR', 'br', 'BR', 'pt-PT' and none of it worked!

My code is like that:

```
<input type="text" name="date" class="form-control" id="date">
```

And the script:

```
    $('#date').datepicker({
        'language' : 'pt-BR',
    });
```

But the calendar is still at english language. How do I change that to portuguese?

Comment: Are you including in the page the translations for your desired language?

Comment: Well... no, I thought the datapicker code had all the languages prepared. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <script type="text/javascript" 
      src="/Resources/plugins/bootstrap-datetimepicker/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" 
      src="/Resources/plugins/bootstrap-datetimepicker/js/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.pt-BR.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>


$("#date").datetimepicker({
    isRTL: false,
    format: 'dd.mm.yyyy hh:ii',
    autoclose:true,
    language: 'pt-BR'
});
```