# How can I do to change the language of a datepicker?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui-datepicker

I would like to change the language of a datepicker. Here is my code :

```
$("#datepicker-month").datepicker({
    locale: 'fr',
    dateFormat: 'mm-yy',
    format: 'yyyy-mm',
    viewMode: "months",
    minViewMode: "months",
    autoclose: true,
    language: "fr",
    regional: "fr",
});
```

But unfortunately I get this :

[datepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrzp9.png)

Could you help me please ?

Comment: Where does `datepicker` method come from? I assume jQuery UI? Which version?

Comment: [Why not read the docs?](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) It is explained clearly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JQuery datepicker language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865091/jquery-datepicker-language)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change language of Bootstrap Datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55595993/change-language-of-bootstrap-datepicker)

Answer (score 0):

Rename all names in your local language.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.fn.datepicker.dates['fr'] = {
        days: ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
        daysShort: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"],
        daysMin: ["Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa"],
        months: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
        monthsShort: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
        today: "Today",
        clear: "Clear",
        format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
        titleFormat: "MM yyyy", /* Leverages same syntax as 'format' */
        weekStart: 0
    };
    $("#datepicker-month").datepicker( {
        format: "mm-yyyy",
        viewMode: "months", 
        minViewMode: "months", 
        language: "fr"
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" id="datepicker-month" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $('#datepicker').datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ "fr" ] );
```

Comment: Assuming current jQuery UI, and assuming the correct localisation file has also been sourced.